Cypress test run, how do I save value across all specs
In my Cypress test I have values that I need to save  and use across specs, for example, when creating an user, I need to store his id to use in other test files. For example I have those files:
test-user.cy.ts:
describe("User Tests", () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.session("userSession", () => {
            cy.login();
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        // More code...
    });

    it("should add user", () => {});

    it("should remove user", () => {});
});

test-company.cy.ts:
describe("Company Tests", () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.session("userSession", () => {
            cy.login();
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        // More code...
    });

    it("should add user", () => {});

    it("should remove user", () => {});
});

In the login I save the user id as below using 'Cypress.env':

const fetchUserCredentials = (): Cypress.Chainable<UserResponse> => {
    return fetchAccessToken().then((access_token) => {
        return cy
            .request({
                method: "POST",
                url: myUrl,
                headers: {
                    // ....
                },
                encoding: "utf8",
                form: true,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
                expect(response.body).to.have.property("email");
                expect(response.body).to.have.property("password");
                expect(response.body).to.have.property("userId");
                Cypress.env("cypress-local-user-id", response.body.userId);
                return cy.wrap(response.body as UserResponse);
            });
    });
};

When I call the login it is saved, but in the second test this value comes as null, I tried to use cy.task, but it did not work.
Could anyone shed a light here on how to save values across spec files?
I tried 'Cypress.env' and 'cy.task'

To use session login across all tests in a spec, use beforeEach instead of before.
To use the same across all specs in the run, move the code to the global support file (default name is cypress/suport/e2e.ts for typescript).
See Writing and Organizing Tests
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.log('I run before every test in every spec file!!!!!!')
})


This file runs before every single spec file.


That's not it, what I want is to save a value and use that value across all specs, I am currently using Cypress.env("key", value), but when trying to access that value in other specs, it does not work.
Another example you be inseting values into the database and saving the Id, but in the other specs I do not want to save that again, I just want the value.

Yes it is, you need to call cy.session() before every test, otherwise you are not using it correctly. (i.e the runner does not call it for you).
